# Windows store app game

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I want to create simple 2D game (touch/click to win) and I have experience with C# and XNA for WP7.

But now at W8 there isn't XNA afaik.

What technologies I have to use for this game?
I want to run it on desktop W8 and WinRT.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hmm. Seems the WinPRT API is all there is to work with: http://www.i-programmer.info/news/189-windows-phone/4559-windows-phone-8-sdk-leaked-no-javascript-apps.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the game is simple enough graphically - you could just use Silverlight on Windows Phone and XAML on Windows 8 which would let you share a lot of the code. Another option is to use XNA on Windows Phone and [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) on Windows 8. MonoGame is an open source version of XNA. Otherwise - on Windows you can use DirectX with C++ or using SharpDX with C#, but these are not available on WP7. They will probably be on WP8 only. Finally - Unity3D support is coming soon, but the final version is not available yet.

Comment: The game will be something like this http://media.flasharcade.com/flashgames/img/Caterpiller%20Smash.jpg I thinking about pure XAML and C#. I do not want support older WP7, I only want support desktop W8, tablet W8 and WP8.

Comment: That should be easily doable in XAML. Until you want to add any special effects that is.